# Insert Query to insert multiple rows in a table via select and output clause. SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a created a stored procedure (please ignore syntax errors)

```
alter proc usp_newServerDetails
   (@appid int, @envid int, @serType varchar(20), @servName varchar(20))
as
    declare @oTbl_sd table (ID int)
    declare @outID1
    declare @oTbl_cd table (ID int)
    declare @outID2

    begin Transaction
        insert into server_details(envid, servertype, servername)
        output inserted.serverid into @oTbl_sd(ID)
        values(@envid, @serType, @servName)

        select @outID1 = ID from @oTbl_sd

        insert into configdetails(serverid, servertype, configpath, configtype)
        output inserted.configid into @oTbl_cd(ID)
        (select @outID1, cm.servertype, cm.configpath, cm.configtype 
         from configpthmaster cm 
         where cm.appid = @appid )

        select @outID2 = ID from @oTbl_cd

        insert into configkeydetails(confiid, keyname)
        output inserted.Keyid into @oTbl_ckd(ID)
        (select @outID2, cm.key 
         from configpthmaster cm 
         where cm.appid = @appid)

    begin 
    commit
    end
```

`server_details` table has an identity column `ID` with is auto-generated ie. `@outID1` and first insert query inserts only 1 row.

`configpthmaster` table is not related to any other table directly and has 2 unique data rows, which I want to fetch to insert data into other tables, one by one during insertion.

The second insert query fetch data from `configpthmaster` table
and insert 2 rows in `configdetails` while generating (auto-generated) ID ie. `@outID2`.

It also has a FK mapped to `server_details`.

The problem is "@outID2" giving last inserted ID only (ie. if two id generated 100,101 i am  getting 101) which eventually on 3rd insertion, inserting 2 rows with same id 101 only but i want the insertion should be linear. i.e one for 100 and other for 101.

If zero rows affected while insertion how to rollback the transaction?

How can I achieve these requirements? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your procedure like below,and try again.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_newServerDetails(@appid int, @envid int,@serType varchar(20),@servName varchar(20))
    AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY

   DECLARE @Output TABLE (ID int,TableName VARCHAR(50),cmKey VARCHAR(50)) --table variable for keeping Inserted ID's

        BEGIN TRAN


         IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM configpthmaster cm  WHERE cm.appid = @appid ) 
                        AND  ( SELECT 1 FROM configkeydetails ck  WHERE ck.appid = @appid ) --add a conditon to satisfy the valid insertions

         BEGIN

            INSERT INTO server_detials(envid,servertype,servername)
                OUTPUT inserted.serverid,'server_detials',NULL INTO @Output(ID,TableName,cmKey )
            VALUES(@envid ,@serType ,@servName)

            INSERT INTO configdetails(serverid,servertype,configpath,configtype)
                OUTPUT inserted.configid,'configdetails',cm.Key INTO @Output(ID,TableName,cmKey )
            SELECT t.ID,cm.servertype,cm.configpath,cm.configtype 
            FROM configpthmaster cm 
              CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID FROM @Output WHERE TableName='server_detials')t
            WHERE cm.appid = @appid

            INSERT INTO configkeydetails(configId,keyname)
            SELECT ID,cmKey FROM @Output 
            WHERE TableName='configdetails'

        END

       COMMIT TRAN
  END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK 

    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Thanks ,but Now while in 3rd insertion  into configkeydetails, result in 0 row affected     :( what i want the id generated in 2nd insertion will used in 3rd and corresponding  value should be stored. @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: @ManojKargeti I think this will work in the same way. It will check whether there any entries in configpthmaster  and configkeydetails  table with the given appid ,then only it will start populate the data. for the Insert in configkeydetails details it will take the inserted configid from the second insert.

Comment: I have executed your provided code but in result in 0 row affected , The insertion on last two table is one to one but using "CROSS APPLY" for 2 entry in  configpthmaster   "SELECT t.ID ,cm.[key] 
            FROM configpthmaster cm 
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID FROM Output WHERE TableName='configdetails')t
            WHERE cm.appid = appid "     giving 4set of  results @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: There will be two entries if there two values in configpthmaster  cooresponding to the given @appid. Say if config master retuns valus 2 and 3 corresponding to a givan appID,the the second insert will contain two rows corresponding to the  inserted server_detials in the first insert table 'server_detials'.

Comment: No please see, SELECT t.ID ,cm.[key]  FROM configpthmaster cm      CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID FROM Output WHERE TableName='configdetails')t
            WHERE cm.appid = appid ** lets say SELECT ID FROM Output WHERE TableName='configdetails' give 100,102 and configpthmaster  have 2 rows with appid 143 and key x  and appid 143 and key y  **the SELECT t.ID ,cm.[key]  will give 100 143 x and 100 143 y ,102 143 x and 102 143 y ????  @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: what i want is, only insert data in configkeydetails same as it is, from configpthmaster with ID newly generated in 2nd insertion , !! is it possible to loop for every insertion in 2nd insert query there will be insertion in 3rd table then again start for 2nd table?@UnnikrishnanR

Comment: @ManojKargeti got it..try out with the updated query.

Comment: could you please guide "try out with the updated query. "  @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: added additional column 'cmKey' to the Output table.So when the second insert happens we will take the  value from 'Key' and saved it to Output table with the inserted ID. So for the third insert we can fetch the required inputs (ie. configIdand keyname) from the output table itself.

Comment: Since we are taking data from the table 'configpthmaster ' for the second and third insert,from the second insert itself ,we can store the required information for the third insert to the output table .

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this solution?

```
alter proc usp_newServerDetails(@appid int, @envid int,@serType varchar(20),@servName varchar(20))
as
declare @oTbl_sd table (ID int)
declare @outID1
declare @oTbl_cd table (ID int)
declare @outID2

begin Transaction

insert into server_detials(envid,servertype,servername)
output inserted.serverid into @oTbl_sd(ID)
values(@envid ,@serType ,@servName)

select @outID1 = ID from @oTbl_sd

insert into configdetails(serverid,servertype,configpath,configtype)
output inserted.configid into @oTbl_cd(ID)
(select @outID1 ,cm.servertype,cm.configpath,cm.configtype from configpthmaster cm where cm.appid = @appid )

select @outID2 = ID from @oTbl_cd
insert into configkeydetails(confiid,keyname)
output inserted.Keyid into @oTbl_ckd(ID)
(select  isnull(replace(stuff((SELECT inserted.configid FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, ''), '&amp;', '&'), '')  ,cm.key, from configpthmaster cm where cm.appid = @appid )

begin 
commit
end
```

I just added STUFF in your code.

The STUFF function inserts a string into another string.

Do take note that using STUFF drastically slows the processing time of the code.

for more information about [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)